# How can I use DI in Quartz JobListener?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, quartz.net

I need to update some fields in the database each time a job starts and ends, keeping this apart from the jobs inner work.

The thing is I have no way to access my db context inside the listener, as the `Scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener` method only receives an instance of the listener. How can I apply dependency injection to the listener in this situation?

Comment: Did you solve it? I am trying to do the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [built-in support for dependency injection](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html). Because listeners are basically singletons I think you need to inject a service provider to the listener and then manually create a scope for resolving for the db context usage.